# Dividing a buffer into segments based on path and distance

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have a buffer layer which I generated from a polyline layer and then dissolved. I then rasterized the dissolved buffer layer, thinned it based on [this link](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Centre-of-the-roads-from-polygons-to-lines-td4978702.html) and generated a new (more approximate) polyline layer which occurs at more or less the centerline of the dissolved buffer layer.

I also have a background raster containing values which I am interested in averaging later on. In summary my session looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to now find a way to segment that buffer layer based on a particular distance. This is the reason I thought that having a centerline polyline layer would be beneficial. In MS paint I have drawn an example of what I am aiming for:

[image]

I'd like to make the segments as perpendicular as possible to the edges of the buffer zone. I realize there is also the problem of how the segments are calculated when the road branches off as shown below. To this I would apply the algorithm employed by v.split.length, if possible.

How do I segment the buffer layer based on a regular centerline length of the dissolved polyline layer?

Comment: it seems like the whole buffer-medial-axis thing you went through aims at a simplification of those initial lines? if so, I think you should rather explore common methods to do so. however, if you need this procedure, it would be easier to segmentize the lines and buffer the segments (check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115687/how-to-achieve-flat-end-line-buffers-in-qgis), although I'm pretty sure the QGIS buffer tool has similar options).

Comment: I might need to add that, with flat caps, there will possibly be gaps between segment buffers...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a programmer, and therefore I will tell you one of the options for solving your problem
1) The initial data line and set distance, see Figure 1

[image]

Split your source line into points in Figure 2

[image]

in any convenient way for you, or in the QGIS tool "Vector-processing geometry-extract nodes" or in PGAdmin.

2) Knowing the length of your line, create a point (points) of your interest, for example, create a temporary table with:

```
create table roadsegment_pt_split1 AS
SELECT ST_LineInterpolatePoint (roadsegments_marge.ggeom, 0.1) as geom
FROM roadsegments_marge
```

The result is shown in Figure 3
[image]

P.S. Wrap everything in a loop and get a set of necessary starting points (tables) on your line.

3) Create a temporary empty point table and copy the points that are before the "insertion point" into it, then copy and add the "insertion point" to the table **at the end of the table**, see Figure 4.

[image]

4) Create a table of type LineString from them

```
create table roadsegment_part1 as
SELECT ST_MakeLine (geom) as geom
FROM roadsegments_pt_split;
```

5) Finally you got the first segment, see Figure 5.

[image]

6) Now create the second segment, create a temporary bitmap, copy the "insertion point" into the beginning of the table! and add all points of your interest from the original dotted line (table) and create from them a second linear segment and so on, see Figure 6.

[image]

```
create table roadsegment_part2 as
SELECT ST_MakeLine (geom) as geom
FROM roadsegment_pt_split2;
```

In this way, you will create a set of line segments of interest to you.

7) Run the following code on your tables (line segments):

```
create table roadsegment_buffer_part1 as
SELECT ST_Buffer ((geom), 0.0001, 'endcap = flat join = round') as geom
FROM roadsegment_part1
```

You can also loop this process for all tables (line segments), as a result, you get what you expect, see Figure 7.

[image]

Programmers can, on the basis of this approach, write a miracle script :-) and all users will gladly use it to solve similar problems.

Comment: well, it is indeed a good hint to consider moving things completely to PostgreSQL/PostGIS. you could have it even simpler than this procedure...,)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not ready to offer a simpler solution now, perhaps it will appear later as my knowledge grows and as a result of my ignorance growth :-),

Comment: ThingumaBob, How do I add a "postgis" tag to this question, or move the "postgis" tag answers to postgis?

Comment: just edit the question itself to add tags. but, tags are set to describe the questions implicit environment; there's no way to tag answers. ...I understand your intentions here, but there's no hint that OP uses PostGIS in this context...and I have the impression that tag would be wrong to set.

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 -

1. Create lines of approximately equal length from lines, the line must be ordered!;
2. Create buffer 2 with semicircular trimmed edges and along the required road width:

```
create table roads_union_byf as
SELECT id, ST_Buffer ((geom), 0.0001,'endcap=round join=round') as geom
FROM roads_split;
```

3. Create boundary lines cut from one side (left):

```
create table roads_cut_l as
SELECT a.id, 
  ST_LineMerge(
    ST_Difference(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom)
  ) geom
FROM roads_union_byf a
LEFT JOIN roads_union_byf b ON (ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) 
AND a.id < b.id);
```

4. Create polygons from them:

```
create table roads_cut_poly_l as
SELECT id, ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(geom, ST_StartPoint(geom))) geom
FROM roads_cut_l;
```

5. Create boundary lines cut from one side (right):

```
create table roads_cut_r as
    SELECT  a.id, 
      ST_LineMerge(
        ST_Difference(ST_ExteriorRing(a.geom), b.geom)
      ) geom
    FROM roads_union_byf a
    LEFT JOIN roads_union_byf b ON (ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) 
    AND a.id > b.id);
```

6. Create polygons from them:

```
create table roads_cut_poly_r as
SELECT id, ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(geom, ST_StartPoint(geom))) geom
FROM roads_cut_r;
```

7. Connect the cut parts of the polygons into a common polygon:

```
create table roads_union_split as
SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as geom
FROM roads_cut_poly_r a, roads_cut_poly_l b
WHERE ST_Intersects (a.geom, b.geom)
AND a.id=b.id;
```

[image]

P.S. Thanks Tilt [Clip overlapping polygon in equal sharing size](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250063/clip-overlapping-polygon-in-equal-sharing-size), good luck

Answer (score 0):

@user32882,The idea of automating the solution of your problem is as follows:

1) Divide your lines into equal segments in any way convenient for you;

2) Create a buffer with rectangular sides from the cut lines by an order of magnitude more than required for the road, for example: for the road - 0.0001, and for the buffer 2 - 0.0003;

3) Extract points from it, while from a number of located points, create centroids;

4) Run the external points (from the buffer 2) the "Delaunay triangulation" tool;

5) Delone polygons in the Delone line and break them;

6) from the center line of the road, extract your points and create small buffers on them;

7) Select from the Delaunay lines, those that fall into the buffer points;

8) from the result 7, cut the road (buffer 1) into almost equal parts, and you will succeed, :-),